# @Jim Green, @JimGreen or @Jim?

Tags: support, comment-replies

Some users' user name contains space. My question is:

> To @ those users whose user names consist of two part, which one of the forms in the title I should use?

Comment: About comment-replies: Basics are explained in [Editing help](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-reply). More details can be found here: [How do comment @replies work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full name should be @JimGreen. But unless there is uncertainty, only the first three characters after the @ are actually referenced (I think). So @Jim would work just as well.

One thing that I never figured out was how to do @t.b.

Comment: There used to be a [bug concerning usernames with dots](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51911/the-dot-in-username-within-first-3-character-preventing-from-comment-replies) which should be now corrected. I think you should go with what autocomplete gives you.

Comment: That last line can be taken out of extreme context, along with some ancient chat jokes about this abbreviation. :-)

Comment: If there is uncertainty, *please* use the full name. There are way to many Alex's on this site, and I'm not to keen on getting pinged every time one of the others is.

Answer (score 1):

My name has a space in it, and if someone I don't know is being polite they should use a space. Similarly, I would use a space for any other user's name if it has a space, and not abbreviate it in any way, unless I have interacted with them a few times and think it is now appropriate. This is the same kind of common courtesy I would use in email or any other form of written communication.

Comment: I agree. It's too bad the autocomplete doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

The comment field auto-completes such usernames to `@JimGreen`. I think both `@Jim` and `@JimGreen` are OK. I expect the first word after the `@` part to be the beginning of the comment, so `@Jim Green` might be a little distracting or confusing.